# Anonymous access to parts of the svn repository

Tags: svn, anonymous-access

I've been looking online and at the other posts on SO to figure out how to add anonymous access to my svn repository but nothing seems to work.  I have the svnaccess.conf file in the directory where my repository is and I have groups setup with read and write access to the project like this:

```
[groups]
admins = administrator
myproject= me

[/]
# give admins read/write access to all repositories
@admins = rw

[myproject:/]
@myproject= rw
```

This works fine for users who have read and write access.  But i want to allow anonymous access to the project so anyone could have read access without having the login screen showup when trying to view the repository.  A lot of the posts i've seen have involved adding * = r and anon-auth = read to the file but when i tried that it still shows the login screen.  Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also add `Satisfy Any` in Apache conf?

Apache conf could be something like this:

```
 <Location /svn/>
   DAV svn
   AuthName "Subversion Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile "htpasswd"
   AuthzSVNAccessFile "authz"

   **Satisfy Any**
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Ok, I assumed you are using Apache to serve the repo.

Comment: do i take out the Require valid-user?  And do i have to restart the server?